# How to include a subfolder controller into other controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to include a subfolder controller to other subfolder controller and sunfolder controller to Controller's controller in laravel.
For example if I create a folder in to controllers folder name admin`(Controllers/admin)` and in admin there are 2 controllers A`(Controllers/admin/AController.php)` and B`(Controllers/admin/BController.php)`  how can I include B into A. And there is a 3rd controller C `(Controllers/CController.php )` in Controllers folder and how can I include controller B in C.

Comment: your question is quite unclear.

Comment: How to include a controller in to other controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the controller exact namespace

**AController**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AController extends Controller
{
    public function getTestA()
    {
        return A;
    }
}
```

**BController**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BController extends Controller
{
    public function getTestB()
    {
        return B;
    }
}
```

Use the `Use` method to call controllers
Must use this use methods

use App\Http\Controllers\admin\AController;
use App\Http\Controllers\admin\BController;

**CController**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\admin\AController;
use App\Http\Controllers\admin\BController;

class CController extends Controller
{
    public function GetA()
    {
        $a = new Acontroller();
        return $a->getTestA();
    }

    public function GetB()
    {
        $b = new Bcontroller();
        return $b->getTestB();
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I include A into B?

Comment: Thanks I figure out I was doing the same thing but I forgot to put http